# How to send a Float value in Today etension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I would like to know how can I send a Float value in a UIlabel in Today extension ?
I try this code:

```
 NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] initWithSuiteName:@"group.mywidget"];
 myfloat = [[sharedDefaults objectForKey:@"float_widget"]floatValue];
 [sharedDefaults synchronize];
```

And to receive the value i use this code:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.mywidget"];
 NSInteger number = [defaults floatForKey:@"float_widget"];
 self.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (float)number];
```

Can you help me please ? thanks

Comment: 1. You do not need `synchronize`. 2. Why do you use `NSInteger` for a `float` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare defaults

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults= [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.mywidge"];
```

Set

```
[defaults setFloat:50.5 forKey:"thisKey"];
```

Read

```
float myfloat = [defaults floatForKey:"thisKey"];
```

Also you should note that there should be app group named `group.mywidge` in capabilities of the main app and the extension